Issue with AddressTools Validation for Guest User in Salesforce LWR Experience Site: "Mailing Country" Field Error
I’m facing an issue with AddressTools validation in Salesforce when using the Guest User profile in an LWR Experience Site. Specifically, I’m encountering the following error:
"'Mailing Country' contains an invalid country name."
This issue occurs only when the Guest User attempts to create or update a Contact record. However, when logged in as a System Admin, I can create the record without any issues. It seems like AddressTools is preventing validation for Guest Users on my LWR Experience Site.
Here’s what I’ve checked so far:

The Mailing Country field is visible and editable for the Guest User profile in Field-Level Security.
The Guest User profile has access to the Contact object and the Mailing Country field.
The relevant AddressTools configuration and validation settings are enabled, but the Guest User seems to be restricted from accessing them properly.
The error is related to AddressTools' country validation, as it works fine for the System Admin.

What I need help with:
Is there a setting in AddressTools that might restrict validation or functionality for specific profiles, especially Guest Users in an LWR Experience Site?
How can I ensure the Guest User profile can successfully pass the country validation check and avoid the "invalid country name" error?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Are you referring to a 3rd party package AddressTools ? If so, you should check with the vendor.
